# Exception while trying to send and receive messages in socket

Tags: python, sockets, encryption

I'm trying to build an encryption chat that used RSA as the encryption algorithm, That the server is waiting for one client, and then when there is a connection, I try to run both methods together. (Receive and send messages).

My problem is that when I run the program, I get an error that says the connection is closed in my opinion. I've been trying to solve this problem for a long time and can't figure out why is it happening.

**Error:**

Client Side: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Server Side: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

**Server Side:**

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

behavior = ['fuck', 'idiot', 'stupid', 'bitch', 'noob',
            'butt', 'penis', 'jerk', 'vagina', 'asshole',
            'dumbass', 'whorebag', 'nutsack', 'motherfucker',
            'bitch', 'shit', 'whore', 'boner', 'dipshit',
            'fuckoff', 'dipshit', 'lardass', 'pissed off',
            'shitfaced', 'douchebag']

def main_text():
    print("""    
\t███╗   ██╗██╗   ██╗██╗  ██╗███████╗
\t████╗  ██║██║   ██║██║ ██╔╝██╔════╝
\t██╔██╗ ██║██║   ██║█████╔╝ █████╗  
\t██║╚██╗██║██║   ██║██╔═██╗ ██╔══╝  
\t██║ ╚████║╚██████╔╝██║  ██╗███████╗
\t╚═╝  ╚═══╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝
\tNuke - RSA Encrypted Chat | Roi Levi
""")

class EncryptedChat:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username.title()
        self.key = RSA.generate(1024) # private_key
        self.public_key = self.key.publickey() # pub_key
        self.token_decryptor  = PKCS1_OAEP.new(self.key)
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as self.sock:
            self.sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 21513))
            self.sock.listen(1)
            print(f'\n\tHey, {self.username}. Waiting for Client: ')
            self.conn, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
            if self.conn:
                print(f'\n\t{self.addr[0]}:{self.addr[1]} Has Connected to the party!\n')
                Thread(target=self.send_msg).start()
                Thread(target=self.recv_msg).start()

    def send_msg(self) -> None:
        ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        while True:
            user_message = input(f'\t{self.username}@{ip_address}: ').encode()
            if user_message.decode().lower() in behavior:
                print('\n\tDo not curse other people, Banned for 30 seconds!')
                sleep(30)
            else:
               self.user_public_key = RSA.importKey(self.conn.recv(1024))
               self.token = PKCS1_OAEP.new(self.user_public_key)
               cipher_text = self.token.encrypt(user_message)
               self.conn.send(cipher_text)

    def recv_msg(self) -> None:
        while True:
            self.conn.send(self.public_key.exportKey())
            cipher_msg = self.conn.recv(1024)
            plain_text = self.token_decryptor.decrypt(cipher_msg)
            print(f'\tRecveived: {plain_text.decode()}')

main_text()
your_username = input('\n\tEnter Username: ')
if your_username in behavior:
    raise ValueError('\n\tInvalid Username, Do not use curse as username!')
else:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            EncryptedChat(your_username)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('\n\tThank you for using our software, Good Bye!')
```

**Client Side:**

```
import socket
from time import sleep
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from threading import Thread

behavior = ['fuck', 'idiot', 'stupid', 'bitch', 'noob',
            'butt', 'penis', 'jerk', 'vagina', 'asshole',
            'dumbass', 'whorebag', 'nutsack', 'motherfucker',
            'bitch', 'shit', 'whore', 'boner', 'dipshit',
            'fuckoff', 'dipshit', 'lardass', 'pissed off',
            'shitfaced', 'douchebag']

def main_text():
    print("""    
\t███╗   ██╗██╗   ██╗██╗  ██╗███████╗
\t████╗  ██║██║   ██║██║ ██╔╝██╔════╝
\t██╔██╗ ██║██║   ██║█████╔╝ █████╗  
\t██║╚██╗██║██║   ██║██╔═██╗ ██╔══╝  
\t██║ ╚████║╚██████╔╝██║  ██╗███████╗
\t╚═╝  ╚═══╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝
\tNuke - RSA Encrypted Chat | Roi Levi
""")

class Client:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username.title()
        self.key = RSA.generate(1024)
        self.public_key = self.key.publickey()
        self.token_decryptor  = PKCS1_OAEP.new(self.key)
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as self.sock:
            self.sock.connect((socket.gethostname(), 21513))
            Thread(target=self.send_msg).start()
            Thread(target=self.recv_msg).start()

    def send_msg(self) -> None:
        ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        while True:
            user_msg = input(f'\t{self.username}@{ip_address}: ').encode()
            if user_msg.decode().lower() in behavior:
                print('\n\tDo not curse other people, Banned for 30 minutes.')
                sleep(30)
            else:
                self.user_public_key = RSA.importKey(self.sock.recv(1024))
                self.token = PKCS1_OAEP.new(self.user_public_key)
                cipher_text = self.token.encrypt(user_msg)
                self.sock.send(cipher_text)

    def recv_msg(self) -> None:
        while True:
            self.sock.send(self.public_key.export_key())
            cipher_msg = self.sock.recv(1024)
            plain_text = self.token_decryptor.decrypt(cipher_msg)
            print(f'\tRecveived: {plain_text.decode()}')

main_text()
your_username = input('\n\tEnter Username: ')
if your_username in behavior:
    raise ValueError('\tDo not use curse as your username!')
else:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            Client(your_username)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('\n\tThank you for using our software, Good Bye!')
```

Comment: Please restrict your code to the essential parts. There is absolutely no need to waste multiple lines with some logo and a offensive word list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, username):
    ...
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as self.sock:
```

The socket gets immediately when you leave the `with ...` block as the following example illustrates:

```
import socket
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    print("inside",s)
print("outside",s)
```

This results

```
inside <socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 0)>
outside <socket.socket [closed] fd=-1, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0>
                       ^^^^^^^^
```

As you can see, the socket is closed outside of the `with ...` block. Thus any operations on `self.sock` inside `send_msg` and `recv_msg` will fail with *"An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket"*.

Thus, instead of using `with ...` just do

```
def __init__(self, username):
    ...
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.connect((self.sock.gethostname(), 21513))
    ...
```

Apart from that on several occassions you don't even use `self.sock` but instead wrongly `socket`. For example in this case:

```
def send_msg(self) -> None:
    ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

Comment: Hey, I understand the problem. But I still have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: @mR-Jacaj: just don't use `with...` - see updated answer.

Comment: @mR-Jacaj: this would then be a different question. But note that using RSA to encrypt user traffic the way you do it is not a good idea for multiple reasons (performance and security related) - usually it is only used to encrypt a symmetric key which is then later used for the real encryption. But again - different question.

Comment: I'm using asymmetric encrypytion algorithm because I don't want to to send my private key because attackers with wireshark or something else can listen to it in the traffic.